# word count in knockoutjs not working correctly

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple text area that I am trying to do a word count for:

```
<textarea rows="20" id="inputText" data-bind="textInput: inputText"></textarea>

<p>Total words: <span id="totalWords" data-bind="text: wordCount"></span></p>
```

when I use jquery the word count works perfectly well:

```
//get the count of words
var val = $.trim($('textarea').val()),
            words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ');
        $('#totalWords').html(words.length);
```

but when I try and do this in knockoutjs it is starting at 1 and incrementing when the first letter of the next word is typed:

```
function appViewModel() {

  this.inputText = ko.observable("");

  this.wordCount = function () {
    var val = $.trim(this.inputText());
    var words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ');
    return words.length;
};
```

...

```
}

ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

ultimately I would like to be able to get the array of words using something like:

```
  this.words = function () {
    var val = $.trim(this.inputText());
    var words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ');
    return words;
};
```

and then use a separate function for the count:

```
this.wordCount = ko.computed(function(){
  return this.words.length;
});
```

because there are other actions I want to perform on the words array - such as a list and count of the number of duplicate words.

Comment: "but when I try and do this in knockoutjs it is starting at 1 and incrementing when the first letter of the next word is typed" what did you expect it to do? Can you give an actual runable example to illustrate your point?

Comment: Also, your `replace` is completely unneeded. You could just `var words = val.split(/\s+/);` and achieve the same result.

Comment: ok, thanks. I don't have a problem with the increment as much as it starting at 1. I'll put on jsfiddle

Comment: Minor issue: `this.words.length` will give you the `length` of the `words` function, which is the number of parameters, `0`. You probably want `this.words().length` instead.

Comment: @GrahamJRoy: If you split an empty string, you'll always end up with one result (the empty string). You may just have to filter out empty strings.

Comment: @MattBurland `''.split('').length` gives `0`. `''.split(' ').length` gives `1`. So that's interesting.

Comment: @Cory, and `''.split(' ').length` yields `1`.

Comment: @Cory: Alight, fair enough, if you split an empty string with anything *other than the empty string* you will get `1`

Comment: @haim770 Yes, I just now noticed that the behavior is totally inconsistent when splitting on non-empty strings versus splitting on the empty string. I guess we wouldn't want to get an infinite array when splitting on the empty string. Wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function appViewModel() {
    this.inputText = ko.observable('');
    this.words = function() {
        return this.inputText().trim().split(' ').filter(function(w) { return !!w; });
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="20" id="textInput" data-bind="textInput: inputText"></textarea>
<p>Total words: <span id="totalWords" data-bind="text: words().length"></span></p>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84L53on7/1/)

Comment: that's perfect @haim770. have you an idea of how to generate an array of duplicate words and the number of times they are duplicated? I am going to output these to the page

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/84L53on7/2/. Not sure about the performance though. You may need to use rateLimit (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) to prevent it from immediately calculate aggregations upon each change.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
function appViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.inputText = ko.observable("");

    this.wordCount = ko.computed(function () {
        var val = self.inputText();
        var words = val.split(/\s+/).filter(function (item) {
            return item.length > 0;
        });
        return words.length;
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="10" id="inputText" data-bind="textInput: inputText"></textarea>
<p>Total words: <span id="totalWords" data-bind="text: wordCount"></span>
</p>
<p data-bind="text: inputText"></p>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to update until you're losing focus. Why not `textInput`?

Comment: @haim770: Because I was originally doing this in JSFiddle where they don't (yet) have an option for knockout 3.2., but as you want.  It really isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: I know it's irrelevant, that's why i was curious as to why you changed it.